# Info button on Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I need you again guys,

I was wondering if there is an info button (like this : "?" http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/256/Button-Help-icon.png) on Twitter Bootstrap (I'm using the 3.2 version).

I've search on google and i've only found basics buttons. I'm seeking a little icon which display infos (as "help") when you're hover. It's for a form.

I'm sorry for my bad, bad english.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: if you won't find anything satisfying in Glyphicons, you can try http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ or try to create your own ones using e.g. http://fontello.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a bootstrap cheatsheet with all the `glyphicons` and `icons` in this website [Glyphicon cheatsheet](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/). There are other sources you can rely on like [Bootstrap components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) or you can simply create your own.
you might also want to try:  `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>` it is similar to the one you want. you can now add the `data-toggle`, `title` and `data-placement` for the tooltip.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="hey tooltip"></span>
```

Make sure you add this javascript at the bottom of your code for the tooltip:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
   })
</script>
```

Comment: That wouldn't display the tooltip "help" as the OP required though.

Comment: oh i see let me improve my answer. give me a sec. thanks for pointing that out.